# Procedure or function 'p_xxx ' has too many arguments specified

Tags: vb.net

I get the error at this line: `sqlDataAdapDelProtocol.Fill(dsDelProtocol, "dsProtocols")`, I dint understand why. The error states : `Procedure or function p_GetLinkedProcuduresProtocol has too many arguments specified`

```
    Protected Sub btnDeletePTC_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim sqlString As String = String.Empty
    Dim PTC_ID As Integer
    sqlString = "p_GetLinkedProcuduresProtocol"

    Dim sqlConnDelProtocol As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(typicalConnectionString("MyConn").ConnectionString)
    sqlConnDelProtocol.Open()

    Dim sqlDataAdapDelProtocol As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlString, sqlConnDelProtocol)
    sqlDataAdapDelProtocol.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure


    Dim sqlParProtocolName As New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@PTC_ID", SqlDbType.Int, 255)
          sqlDataAdapDelProtocol.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParProtocolName)

    Dim dsDelProtocol As New DataSet
    Dim MessageAud = "Are you sure you want to delete this question, the question is linked to:"
    Dim MessageNoAud = "Are you sure you want to delete this question"


    sqlDataAdapDelProtocol.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("PTC_ID", PTC_ID)
    sqlDataAdapDelProtocol.Fill(dsDelProtocol, "dsProtocols")

    If dsDelProtocol.Tables("dsProtocols").Rows.Count > 0 Then
        lblMessageSure.Text = (CType(MessageAud, String))
        For Each dr As DataRow In dsDelProtocol.Tables(0).Rows
            lblAudits = (dr("dsProtocols"))
        Next
    Else
        lblMessageSure.Text = (CType(MessageNoAud, String))
    End If

    Dim success As Boolean = False

    Dim btnDelete As Button = TryCast(sender, Button)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(btnDelete.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)

          Dim cmdDelete As New SqlCommand("p_deleteProtocolStructure")
    cmdDelete.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmdDelete.Parameters.AddWithValue("PTC_ID", PTC_ID)

    Call DeleteProtocol(PTC_ID)

    conn = NewSqlConnection(connString, EMP_ID)
    cmdDelete.Connection = conn

    If Not conn Is Nothing Then
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            Try
                success = cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Call UpdateProtocolNumbering(PTS_ID)
                txtAddPTCNumber.Text = GetNextNumber(PTS_ID)
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "TreeView", _
                "<script language='javascript'>" & _
                "   parent.TreeView.location='TreeView.aspx?MainScreenURL=Protocols.aspx&PTS_ID=" & PTS_ID & "';" & _
                "</script>")

                conn.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                success = False
                conn.Close()
                Throw ex
            End Try
        End If
    End If

    If success = True Then
        Call GenerateQuestionsGrid()
        Call Message(Me, "pnlMessage", "Question successfully deleted.", Drawing.Color.Green)
    Else
        Call Message(Me, "pnlMessage", "Failed to delete Question.", Drawing.Color.Red)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure your parameters you define in store procedure and you define in your code matching exactly?

Comment: @SonerGönül yes they are, just made sure now.

Comment: So does the error message actually quote `p_xxx` as the procedure or function? If so, then perhaps the proc you are calling calls another and doesn't call it correctly.

Comment: no it quotes `p_GetLinkedProcuduresProtocol`, sorry

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the same parameter twice, once without a value, then with a value. Instead of adding it another time, set the value on the parameter that you already have.

Replace this:

```
sqlDataAdapDelProtocol.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("PTC_ID", PTC_ID)
```

with this:

```
sqlParProtocolName.Vaue = PTC_ID
```

Side note: Always start parameter names for Sql Server with `@`. The parameter constructor will add it if it's not there so it will work without it, but this is an undocumented feature, so that could change in future versions.